# Detect how a subroutine is called in Perl

Tags: perl, subroutine

I would like to detect how a subroutine is called so I can make it behave differently depending on each case:

```
# If it is equaled to a variable, do something:
$var = my_subroutine();

# But if it's not, do something else:
my_subroutine();
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [wantarray](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html)

```
if(not defined wantarray) {
    # void context: foo()
}
elsif(not wantarray) {
    # scalar context: $x = foo()
}
else {
    # list context: @x = foo()
}
```

Comment: There is also http://p3rl.org/Want module, but for this case it might be overkill.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, what you're looking for is [`wantarray`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub foo{
  if(not defined wantarray){
    print "Called in void context!\n";
  }
  elsif(wantarray){
    print "Called and assigned to an array!\n";
  }
  else{
    print "Called and assigned to a scalar!\n";
  }
}

my @a = foo();
my $b = foo();
foo();
```

This code produces the following output:

```
Called and assigned to an array!
Called and assigned to a scalar!
Called in void context!
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a powerful and very useful XS module called [Want](https://metacpan.org/pod/Want) developed by Robin Houston. It extends what the core perl function wantarray() offers and enables you to find out if your method for example was called in an object context.

```
$object->do_something->some_more;
```

Here in `do_something` you could write before returning:

```
if( want('OBJECT') )
{
    return( $object );
}
else
{
    return; # return undef();
}
```